Ubuntu Dock turns itself back on after turning it off
Ubuntu 24.04, and I install all updates as they are available.
I'm using the Gnome extension Dash to Panel, and I turn off the Ubuntu Dock. Yesterday, the dock was back at the same time having the Dash to Panel active. Very irritating. I went into settings, and the switch for Ubuntu Dock was colored as though it was ON, but was in the OFF position. I toggled it on and off, and the dock disappeared. On next login, it was back. I keep having to do this on each login. I don't power off or restart, but I have a couple of times since this started to see if it would help, but it comes back. I generally just lock screen and unlock later, and the dock returns.
In addition to the dock returning constantly, the dock is now visible in the bottom center, floating, when I pull up the overview screen or in the all apps screen using "super-A" key.
I really would like the dock to go away. Haven't upgraded to 24.10, I'm staying on 24.04.
How to get rid of the dock? (Since I use dock to panel, I can't just uninstall the dock, or at least I am unsure if it would break that extension.)

Turns out the problem is with an update to Dash to Panel extension. There is a fix for it here -> https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/2199
Just have to rename /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com to /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak

Thanks for linking, appears to have fixed it for me.
